# How to calculate how far two points expand from each other depending on their distance during inflation?

Tags: cosmology, cosmological-inflation

I'm trying to find a relationship between two points that are $\ell$ distance apart $N_0$ e-folds into inflation, assuming there are 60 e-folds total and inflation starts at 60 and ends at 0, and their distance from each other in the present day universe.

In other words, I would like $\ell_{0}(N_0, \ell)$, where $\ell_0$ is the distance in the present day universe.

Does anyone know how I could approach this?

Comment: Have you tried googling "efolds during standard inflation". I found a few promising pdf's there.

Comment: I have, but can't find anything that helps me try and get this relation which depends solely on their distance at some arbitrary efold.

Comment: The lecture notes "*Inflationary cosmology*" by Julien Lesgourgues, LAPTH, Annecy-Le-Vieux, France", was on the results list that I have searched and it gives a very good discussion of the efolds needed to solve the various issues of the standard LCDM model. It also depends on which inflation model you use. I have only done the calculation for the simplest inflationary model, and that was along time ago, but the lecture notes  should enable you to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a log-log plot of work that I have done some 15 years ago, as part of a presentation to a group of engineers. It is based on the simplest inflation model of that time, Alan Guth's original inflation and LCDM expansion.

[image: Log-log plot of 60 efold total expansion]

t_P and r_P are Planck time and length, with t and r in the standard IUs and r equivalent to your *ℓ*.

I hope it helps, Bajo

Comment: My old diagram obviously shows 60 ten-folds over the total age, not e-folds. It was 35 ten-folds of inflation and 25 ten-folds since the end of inflation. I think the modern values are highly inflation model-dependent.

Comment: Thank you, you've given me an idea! Appreciate the help!